# Windows 10 UWP USSD Protocol example not working

Tags: mobile, uwp, ussd

I want to use the ussd ptotocol in my mobile broadband application. I found the following example from the Universal Windows Platform samples collection:
[Link to this example on github](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/UssdProtcol)

I use the huawei K5150 UMTS Stick, which is redomended from Microsoft. But wenn i test this example i am getting an error:
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lCeH.jpg)

```
Unexpected exception occured: System.Exception from HRESULT: 0xC004000A
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNunSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
at USSDApi.RequestResponse. <SendButton_Click>d_3.MoveNext()
```

Can anyone help me with this error? How can i debug it? Is this example not working?